# Can I use the same trigger for insert and update?

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE OR REPLACE
    /*[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]*/
    TRIGGER `goods_input_total_amount-updateon-goods_input` BEFORE UPDATE
    ON `gym`.`goods_input`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE input_price INTEGER; /*use whatever datatype you have in your db for the price */
        SELECT price_goods_input_price INTO input_price FROM goods_input_price
        WHERE id_goods_input_price=NEW.id_goods_input_price LIMIT 1;
        SET new.goods_input_total_amount=new.goods_input_quantity*input_price;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The syntax is working for "before insert" trigger but I got this error message:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'TRIGGER
>   `goods_input_total_amount-updateon-goods_input` BEFORE UPDATE
>       ON `gy' at line 3

Comment: You left the `/[DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]/` section in the create trigger...

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER` is not there in MySQL

Try

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE 
    TRIGGER `goods_input_total_amount-updateon-goods_input` BEFORE UPDATE
    ON `gym`.`goods_input`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE input_price INTEGER; /*use whatever datatype you have in your db for the price */
        SELECT price_goods_input_price INTO input_price FROM goods_input_price
        WHERE id_goods_input_price=NEW.id_goods_input_price LIMIT 1;
        SET new.goods_input_total_amount=new.goods_input_quantity*input_price;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you want to delete an existing TRIGGER, use

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS Trigger_name
```

before the `create trigger` code